# Laravel 5 and PHPUnit view test fails - headers already sent

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit

I have a freshly set up Laravel 5 project with a working site on "/". When I try to run the provided feature test `tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php` with `PHPUnit 5.7.21` I receive status code 500.

```
1) Tests\Feature\ExampleTest::testBasicTest
Expected status code 200 but received 500.
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

The test class is as provided.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

The returned page as being part of `$response` states the following error.

```
ini_set(): Cannot change zlib.output_compression - headers already sent
```

I did not change any value in the provided PHPUnit config file.

In my middleware I use the compression to ensure a compressed output of the website.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AfterMiddleware {
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'On');
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

When I uncomment the `ini_set` line, all goes well. What can I do to enable compression and be able to run PHPUnit?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your `ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'On');` Edit the php.ini file , then it will be available globaly your application.

```
zlib.output_compression = On
```

If you use `php --ini` you will get list of used ini files and its path  used